# Simplifying counting operation in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following code to count the number of times a value is higher than average and lower than average, then appends the value to a new column at the month stating whether it has more values higher than average or lower than average. However the code is quite an eyesore and I would like to know if there are any ways to simplify/beautify it.

```
from collections import Counter

df4 = df[['Date', 'dv']].copy()
df4.set_index(['Date'], inplace=True)
data = df4.to_period('M')
data.reset_index(inplace=True)

gb = data.groupby(['Date'])
result = gb['dv'].apply(list)
result = result.to_frame(name='dv2')
result.reset_index(inplace=True)


def mv(x):
    keys = Counter(x).keys()
    values = Counter(x).values()

    keys = list(keys)
    values = list(values)

    if np.nan in keys:
        return np.nan
    else:
        if len(keys) == 1:
            return keys[0]
        else:
            if values[0] > values[1]:
                return keys[0]
            else:
                return keys[1]


result['mv'] = result['dv2'].apply(lambda x: mv(x))
del result['dv2']

df4.reset_index(inplace=True)
data = df4[['Date', 'dv']].copy()
data.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
data_monthly = data.reset_index().groupby([data.index.year, data.index.month], as_index=False).last()

data_monthly['mv'] = data_monthly['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m').map(result.set_index(result['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m'))['mv'])
df4['mv'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%D').map(data_monthly.set_index(data_monthly['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%D'))['mv'])
```

This is the dataframe before:

```
         Date      dv
0  2010-01-02     NaN
1  2010-01-12     NaN
2  2010-01-23     NaN
3  2010-02-02     NaN
4  2010-02-13     NaN
5  2010-02-24     NaN
6  2010-03-03  Higher
7  2010-03-13  Higher
8  2010-03-24  Higher
9  2010-04-02  Higher
10 2010-04-14   Lower
11 2010-04-25  Higher
12 2010-05-05  Higher
13 2010-05-15   Lower
14 2010-05-26   Lower
15 2010-06-03   Lower
16 2010-06-14  Higher
17 2010-06-25  Higher
```

This is the dataframe after:

```
         Date      dv      mv
0  2010-01-02     NaN     NaN
1  2010-01-12     NaN     NaN
2  2010-01-23     NaN     NaN
3  2010-02-02     NaN     NaN
4  2010-02-13     NaN     NaN
5  2010-02-24     NaN     NaN
6  2010-03-03  Higher     NaN
7  2010-03-13  Higher     NaN
8  2010-03-24  Higher  Higher
9  2010-04-02  Higher     NaN
10 2010-04-14   Lower     NaN
11 2010-04-25  Higher  Higher
12 2010-05-05  Higher     NaN
13 2010-05-15   Lower     NaN
14 2010-05-26   Lower   Lower
15 2010-06-03   Lower     NaN
16 2010-06-14  Higher     NaN
17 2010-06-25  Higher  Higher
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `resample` and `agg` to get the maximum date and most common value for each month
2. `merge` back to original dataframe and `rename`

```
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
modes = df.resample("M", on="Date".agg({"Date": "max",
                                        "dv": lambda x: x.mode()[0] if not x.mode().empty else np.nan}
                                       ).reset_index(drop=True))
output = df.merge(modes.rename(columns={"dv": "mv"}), how="left")

>>> output
         Date      dv      mv
0  2010-01-02     NaN     NaN
1  2010-01-12     NaN     NaN
2  2010-01-23     NaN     NaN
3  2010-02-02     NaN     NaN
4  2010-02-13     NaN     NaN
5  2010-02-24     NaN     NaN
6  2010-03-03  Higher     NaN
7  2010-03-13  Higher     NaN
8  2010-03-24  Higher  Higher
9  2010-04-02  Higher     NaN
10 2010-04-14   Lower     NaN
11 2010-04-25  Higher  Higher
12 2010-05-05  Higher     NaN
13 2010-05-15   Lower     NaN
14 2010-05-26   Lower   Lower
15 2010-06-03   Lower     NaN
16 2010-06-14  Higher     NaN
17 2010-06-25  Higher  Higher
```

Note: `pd.Series.mode` will return a list of the most common values if there is more than one. The code above keeps only *one* mode if it exists (January in your example has all `NaN` and therefore no mode).